# How to manage VM guest from Hyper-V Core host?

Tags: hyper-v

A dedicated server is running Hyper-V Core with the GUI extensions, and it has a Windows Server VM.  I set things up with NAT so that from my laptop I can remote into that VM.

I need the capability to connect remotely into the host, and from the host, manage the VM guests, either with Hyper-V Manager or by remoting into the VM from the host, but not sure how to make that possible with Core.

The reason I want to do this is that the VM is accessible to attackers, and I want to set a firewall setting in the VM so only I can remote into it. If my ISP changes my IP, I want to make sure I can access the host, and then from there manage the VM to change the IP in the firewall.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to make sure that your VM's are in a virtual network that is reachable from the host, you could use external for that.

You could then install Windows Admin Center on a client pc to manage the Hyper-V role
https://petri.com/how-to-install-hyper-v-on-windows-server-core/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/manage/windows-admin-center/use/manage-virtual-machines#manage-a-virtual-machine-through-the-hyper-v-host-vmconnect

Comment: Thanks, but not what I asked.  I want to remote into the VM from the host it's on, which is running Hyper-V Core (no desktop) with the UI extensions.

Comment: What do you mean with Remote? Do you want to use the VMConnect console to connect to the VM, or do you want to use remote powershell?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear.  By Remote, I meant Remote Desktop, but opening the VM within Hyper-V Manager on the host would be fine too, but not sure how I can install that on Hyper-V Core.

Comment: After some research I found that RDP is available on Server Core. So to RDP from the host to a VM you need to put a VM in a virtual network that is available from the host and enable RDP in the VM. If you want to i can elaborate a bit more about it in an edit of my answer. But keep in mind that this is not the purpose of how server core should be used, you should manage it remotely.